# Cumulative Sum of Pubsub Unacked Messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, mql, google-cloud-pubsublite

I want to get the TOTAL number of messages received by a subscription during a 3 day time period. However, I cannot just use the view of unacked messages as during this 3 day period as many messages were ack'ed and processed. I want to see the total messages received (ignoring whether they were acked or not)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkeMD.png)

In this case, it should be a sum that totals to around ~200M.

I have tried using MQL to get the sum during this period but was unable to come up with a correct query.